# how to create user define tables by ADO.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

A desktop-based software shall enable a user to create tables in a provided database as per requirement.
My problem is that ExecuteNonQuery treats only Data Manipulation Language.

What should i use for Data Definition Language, i.e to pass create command.

Thanks in advance :)
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAMMb.png)

#### 3rd party edit

From the linked image

```
public void create(string name, int varchar_quantity, string rate)
{
    con.Close();
    string s = "Crate table anas('" + name + "' varchar ('" 
                     + varchar_quantity + "')" + rate + "' int);";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create tables with `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation,

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

```
var conStr = "PUT YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE";
using (var c = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    c.Open();
    var qry = "CREATE TABLE TEST(name varchar(30));";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still having some problem. plz help

Comment: What is the problem ? You did not say that and i am not wearing my superman pajama today!

Comment: this code above is not passing create commomd. what else should i have to add in this code. kindly explain briefly, i am new at programming. thanx in advance.